# Unintended change on defined constant's value

Tags: php, constants

Is there any explanation of this strange behavior of defined constant?
I have 1 file (`config.php`) which hold predefined value of directories, something like this

```
$dir =  array
(
    'core_dir'     => 'includes',
    'admin_dir'    => 'admin',
    'upload_dir'   => 'uploads',
    'template_dir' => 'templates'
);
define('SCRIPT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

foreach($dir as $name => $location)
{
    if ( !is_dir($location) AND is_dir(SCRIPT_DIR.$location))
        $dir[$name] = SCRIPT_DIR.$location;
}
define('CORE_DIR',$dir['core_dir'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ADMIN_DIR',$dir['admin_dir'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('UPLOAD_DIR',$dir['upload_dir'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('TEMPLATE_DIR',$dir['template_dir'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

file layout as follow

```
+root_dir
|_index.php
|_config.php
+-includes
| |_javascript.js
+-admin
  |_index.php
```

This file then included on index.php and /admin/index.php. When I use this constant on main directory:

```
echo $config['site_url'].CORE_DIR.'js/javascript.js';
```

with `$config['site_url']` was full site URL. It works perfectly:

```
http://localhost/elearning/includes/js/javascript.js
//which means CORE_DIR = includes/
```

However when I use the **same** code under admin directory, I get:

```
http://localhost/elearning//home/bam/www-data/elearning/includes/js/javascript.js
//which means CORE_DIR = /home/bam/www-data/elearning/includes/ o.O
```

I know that the based on the config, when relative path not found, it will automatically change to absolute path **before** the constant defined. But how come same code run on same machine give different output when working on different directory?

Is there something wrong with my code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this: if ( !is_dir($location) AND is_dir(SCRIPT_DIR.$location)) ?

Comment: @Pies: my fault, that was intended to deal with relative/absolute include path and indeed pretty useless when used on URL build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this from `index.php`, the `CORE_DIR` constant is not added because the condition

```
 if ( !is_dir($location) AND is_dir(SCRIPT_DIR.$location))
```

is not met (because `$location` exists).

When you run it from another directory, `is_dir($location)` is not true any more.

You should remove the first check. That said, I'm not sure whether the whole construction makes sense. Why not use absolute URLs from the start?

Comment: nevermind my last comment, I have to do some workaround ad finally success. Thanks for correction :)